# AwsStringStream.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am working on the tutorial in this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-cmake-exports-with-the-aws-sdk-for-c/).
I have all libraries and aws-cpp-sdk are installed.
I have aws folder inside /usr/local/include.

```
When I make the cpp file, I have error as 
 sudo make
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/Softwares/Projects/S3upload/build
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/S3upload.dir/S3upload.cpp.o
/home/Softwares/Projects/S3upload/S3upload.cpp:4:56: fatal error: aws/core/utils/memory/stl/AwsStringStream.h: No such file or directory
 #include <aws/core/utils/memory/stl/AwsStringStream.h> 
                                                        ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/S3upload.dir/S3upload.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/S3upload.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What could be wrong?
My cpp file is

```
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.h>
#include <aws/core/utils/memory/stl/AwsStringStream.h> 

using namespace Aws::S3;
using namespace Aws::S3::Model;


static const char* KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";//"s3_cpp_sample_key";
static const char* BUCKET = "xxxxxx";//"s3-cpp-sample-bucket";

int main()
{
    S3Client client;

    //first put an object into s3
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest;
    putObjectRequest.WithKey(KEY)
           .WithBucket(BUCKET);

    //this can be any arbitrary stream (e.g. fstream, stringstream etc...)
    auto requestStream = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::StringStream>("s3-sample");
    *requestStream << "Hello World!";

    //set the stream that will be put to s3
    putObjectRequest.SetBody(requestStream);

    auto putObjectOutcome = client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);

    if(putObjectOutcome.IsSuccess())
    {
        std::cout << "Put object succeeded" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error while putting Object " << putObjectOutcome.GetError().GetExceptionName() << 
               " " << putObjectOutcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;  
}
```

My CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(S3upload)

#this will locate the aws sdk for c++ package so that we can use its targets
#/usr/src/Softwares/AWSC++SDK/aws-sdk-cpp/build/
find_package(aws-sdk-cpp)

add_executable(S3upload S3upload.cpp)

#since we called find_package(), this will resolve all dependencies, header files, and cflags necessary
#to build and link your executable. 
target_link_libraries(S3upload aws-cpp-sdk-s3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that aws/core/utils/memory/stl/AwsStringStream.h exists under /user/local/include ? Note that the file name is case sensitive, are you sure that the file name is AwsStringStream.h ?

Comment: Yes aws folder is included in /usr/local/include in installation. Yes very sure file name is AwsStringStream.h.

Comment: Yeah file name has some issue. I copied from the link and it has problem. Now I rewrite the file name and no more error.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your header files in quotation marks and check to see if they really are in the correct directory